# Python call function from user input

Tags: python

Can you call functions from user input? Something like this:

```
def testfunction(function):
    function()

a = raw_input("fill in function name: "
testfunction(a)
```

So if you fill in an existing function it will execute it.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is bad bad bad :P However, it's perfectly possible.

```
a = raw_input("Fill in function name:")
if a in locals().keys() and callable(locals()['a']):
    locals()['a']()
else:
    print 'Function not found'
```

`locals()` returns a dictionary of all the objects currently avalible, and their names. So when we say `a in locals().keys()` we are saying, "Is there any object called ". If there is, we then get it by doing `locals()['a']` and then test if it is a function using `callable`. If that is `True` aswell, then we call the function. If it is not, we simply print `"Function not found"`.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably encapsulate this kind of behavior in a class:

```
class UserExec(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = "hello"
    def get_command(self):
        command = str(raw_input("Enter a command: "))
        if not hasattr(self, command):
            print "%s is not a valid command" % command
        else:
            getattr(self, command)()
    def print_msg(self):
        print self.msg
a = UserExec()
a.get_command()
```

As others have said, this is a security risk, but the more control you have over the input, the less of a risk it is; putting it in a class that includes careful input vetting helps.

Comment: is this procedure version specific? Will Python 3.x look any different?

Comment: @ArashHowaida A little different, but it's basic stuff, nothing unexpected or unusual -- in this case just `print` and `raw_input` need changing. I always advise that people familiarize themselves with the difference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, though this is generally a bad idea and a big security risk.

```
def testfunc(fn):
    fn()

funcname = raw_input('Enter the name of a function')
if callable(globals()[funcname]):
    testfunc(globals()[funcname])
```