# Calling a function, stored as a value in a dictionary, if the user's input matches the value's key

Tags: python

I'm currently creating a simple interactive fiction (IF) game in Python. In addition to the commands relevant to each room they explore, I would like for the player to have access to a list of "global commands" that can be called at anytime (inventory, help, etc).

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134482/python-call-function-from-user-input) thread to get started, but I don't think it's quite what I'm looking for.

Essentially, what I want is something like this (obviously, not all of this is valid code):

```
def inventory():
    # Shows the user's inventory

def game_help():
    # shows a list of available commands

global_commands = {
    'inventory': inventory(),
    'help': game_help(),
}

command = raw_input().downcase()
if command == "get item":
     print "You take the item"
elif command == "open door":
     print "You open the door"
elif command in global_commands:
     # execute the function that is tied to the user's input
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: `global_commands[command]()`. The `global_command[command]` part gets the value which is a function that you can call with `()`

Comment: There is no such thing as `downcase()`. You want `lower()`.

Comment: @idjaw - Derp. Lol. Thank you for mentioning that. Another language was bleeding over in my mind (Ruby).

Comment: globals().get(command)()

Comment: @T.Claverie - Can you submit that as an answer so I can accept it, please and thank you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the values in the global_commands dictionary the functions. Don't include parentheses as you don't want to call them yet.

```
global_commands = {
    'inventory': inventory,
    'help': game_help,
}
```

Then look up the command in the dictionary and execute the corresponding function:

```
elif command in global_commands:
    global_commands[command]()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, you can also pass functions into other functions this way, by using their name without the brackets to call them.

Comment: The text is wrong. The dictionary values aren't the names of the functions, they **are** the functions.

Comment: It was working fine when I tested it (created a new file to do so) but when I try to run my characterCreation script, I get the following error: "name 'inventory' is not defined" referring to my "inventory" function. Any thoughts? Should I post the code as an answer?

Comment: Create a [minimal complete working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) That is a script that is a concise as possible but still shows the problem.